# How to get RefCell to an object and Rc to its part

Tags: rust

I need to call a mut method on an object from one callback and another method from another callback (a timer and request animation frame in a webasm thing) on its field returned from that object. Whatever I tried I was getting various errors, mostly like 'creates a temporary which is freed while still in use'. Is it ever possible?

```
let mut top = Top {
    item: Item {}
};

let top_rc_refcell = Rc::new(RefCell::new(top));


let top_rc_1 = Rc::clone(&top_rc_refcell);

let box_1 = Box::new(move || {
    top_rc_1.borrow_mut().some_mut();
});
let top_rc_2 = Rc::clone(&top_rc_refcell);
//ref_to_item is costly so calling it from within callback is not an option
let item_rc = Rc::new(&top_rc_2.borrow().ref_to_item());

let item_rc_in_box = Rc::clone(&item_rc);

let box_2 = Box::new(move || {
    item_rc_in_box.some();
});

(box_1)();
(box_2)();
```

Errors:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:46:28
   |
46 |     let item_rc = Rc::new(&top_rc_2.borrow().ref_to_item());
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                            |
   |                            creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
47 | 
48 |     let item_rc_in_box = Rc::clone(&item_rc);
   |                                    -------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:46:28
   |
46 |     let item_rc = Rc::new(&top_rc_2.borrow().ref_to_item());
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                            |
   |                            creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
47 | 
48 |     let item_rc_in_box = Rc::clone(&item_rc);
   |                                    -------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=163874d492092e1e4cf760f402ae9951)

Comment: Please post the full error(s) from `cargo check`.

Comment: Missing definitions of `Top` and `Item`

Comment: `let item_rc = Rc::new(&top_rc_2.borrow().ref_to_item());` is weird; there is no point in creating an `Rc` that contains a reference. The whole point of an `Rc` is to take ownership of an object, so it can go out of scope and keep it alive while other instances of `Rc` still exist. If the content of `Rc` itself is a reference, the original object will never be allowed to go out of scope and you could simply use the original reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. You cannot create a `Rc` pointing to the field because the field will have to be wrapped somehow in the `Rc`. You can only do so for a pointer to the field, and this is pretty useless and also the source of your errors.

You need to either declare the field as `Rc` or just use the whole-object `Rc`.

Comment: yep, works perfectly - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70059d762633b9aefcc99800c497911a , thank you!